# Trouble Connecting with BigCommerce API

Tags: api, curl, bigcommerce

I'm using the following to try and test a GET request on the BigCommerce API locally, but I'm getting a "Failed to connect to api.bigcommerce.com port 443: Connection refused". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

````
$api_url = 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/STORE-HASH/v3/customers';


$headers = array(
"Accept: application/json",
"Content-Type: application/json",
"X-Auth-Client: xxxxxxxx",
"X-Auth-Token:xxxxxxxx"
);

$chbig = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chbig, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url); 
curl_setopt($chbig, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($chbig, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt( $chbig, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $chbig, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $chbig, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$result = curl_exec($chbig); //execute request
$http_status =  (string) curl_getinfo($chbig, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if(curl_errno($chbig))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($chbig);
}


curl_close($chbig);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($http_status);
print_r($result);```
````

Answer (score 0):

I really like to use Postman for testing out my API requests. You may want to [download](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) that as well, if you have not already.
Here is the code that I am using to connect to my customers

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{STORE_HASH}/v3/customers",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "X-Auth-Token: {TOKEN}",
    "X-Auth-Client:{CLIENT_ID}"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); // makes the request

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

You may be having issues due to the Accept and/or Content-type headers. I would remove those headers and only use the 'X-Auth-Token' and 'X-Auth-Client' headers for GET requests. Good luck!